# I have a raspberry pi can i use minecraft and tunneling with localhost.run

Tags: ssh-tunneling, minecraft

Hey i have a raspberry pi with raspbian installed Im wonder if i could use localhost.run which is a website that allows tunneling with ssh could i use this with a mc server looking to run java edition if would it be secure and would it be reliable?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have a look around the internet at how people are running Minecraft server - IIRC it does not play nice as a daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this, and it didn't work for a Minecraft server. Here's what it looks like in a terminal if you did make the connection to localhost.run:

[image: Screenshot of terminal accessing localhost.run via ssh]

However, when I ran Minecraft and tried to connect to the server, it fails. I am not convinced this can be made to work, as the service is designed for exposing secure web services, not arbitrary applications or game servers.

Comment: Wonder if telebit could work